# how to retraive document list from google docs in android?

Tags: android, gdata-api

is there any way to working with google docs in android. i seem that a java client library is not support with android.

Please help me out!

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: I suggest you investigate the code of MyTracks: 
 http://code.google.com/p/mytracks/ 

They have a pretty well documented set of Java files that rely on
accessing the Google Documents API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple and easiest way to access gdocs from android [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-spreadsheet-lib-android/)

Use and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Read this : 
[Java android client api for android](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android)

then take a look at a [sample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/docs/DocumentList.java) that gets a document list from google docs.

Comment: Thanks For Reply. Please one more help. please give me list of library that i have to  add.